# How to Make an edge between two nodes of two different graphs in DSE?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax-java-driver, datastax-enterprise-graph, datastax-startup

I am using Datastack(DSE) i'm not able to find out how to make an Edge between two nodes of two different graphs(notebook)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to create edges between two different graphs. Chances are, if you want to do that then you don't actually have 2 graphs.

You *can* use the same graph from multiple notebooks, if that helps.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, i have one user notebook and one product notebook so how to make an edge between these two notebook nodes

Comment: I think it seems like the aspect you're missing is that both notebooks can use the same graph, so you can perform any operations you want from either notebook. However, it sounds like what you probably want to do is simply use a single notebook for a while - at least until you're more comfortable with the system and how all the pieces fit together. I don't know exactly what you're doing but 1 notebook should work out well.